# Why Expression.And represents "&" but not "&&"

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I have the following class:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm creating and Expression tree of type `Expression<Func<Test, bool>>` on this class. When I do it like this:

```
Expression<Func<Test, bool>> predicate1 = x => x.Text.Length > 5 && x.Number > 0;
```

I get the following debug view:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[NHLinqTest.Test,System.Boolean]>(NHLinqTest.Test $x) {
    ($x.Text).Length > 5 && $x.Number > 0
}
```

note: there's a `&&` for and-operation.
When I do it like this:

```
    var y = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test));

    var predicate2 = Expression.And(
        Expression.GreaterThan(
            Expression.Property(Expression.Property(y, "Text"), "Length"),
            Expression.Constant(5)),
    Expression.GreaterThan(
        Expression.Property(y, "Number"),
            Expression.Constant(0)));
```

I get the following debug view:

```
($var1.Text).Length > 5 & $var1.Number > 0
```

Note: there's `&` for and-operation. Why do I get `&` in the second case? How to modify `predicate2` to get `&&` instead of `&`?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because it **is** `&` - i.e. bitwise / non-short-circuiting "and". For `&&` you want `Expression.AndAlso`.

See also `Expression.Or` (`|`) vs `Expression.OrElse` (`||`).

Also, note that `Expression` != C# - it is language independent, so you might *also* see some cases where you *don't* get back (visually) what you would expect from C#.

Answer (score 5):

Compare [Expression.And](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301748.aspx):

> Creates a BinaryExpression that represents a bitwise AND operation.

and [Expression.AndAlso](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353520.aspx):

> Creates a BinaryExpression that represents a conditional AND operation that evaluates the second operand only if the first operand evaluates to true.

And then compare that to your knowledge of the `&` and `&&` operators.

Answer (score 3):

The "&" operator and Expression.And represent a bitwise and.  The "&&" operator and Expression.AndAlso represent a logical (and short-cutting) and operator.